# making numbers be on one line in python

Tags: python, string

I have a `list = [1, 2, 3]`

I want this to be printed `1, 2, 3`

However, when I use:

```
for number in list:
     print(num)
```

the number gets printed:

```
1

2

3
```

Comment: Technically, this is _not_ a duplicate. The OP implies that he would want to use a `for` loop construct. And none of the answers in the referred question provides a direct answer to this requirement.

Comment: @lifebalance Literally the first answer of that duplicate uses a loop.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If that answer could be _trivially_ modified to provide for a `comma` separator (as indicated by the OP), I would have gladly linked to that answer myself, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `alist = [1, 2, 3]`

```
print(alist)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

If you don't want the square brackets,

```
print(', '.join(str(i) for i in alist)
# 1, 2, 3
```

If you want to print only the elements,

```
print (*alist)
# 1 2 3
```

If you insist on using a `for` loop,

```
for i in alist[:-1]: 
    print(i, end = ", ")
print(alist[-1])
# 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for the `string.join` function

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
print(', '.join(map(str, items))
```

which would give

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found` and you are missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: @cireo join can be applied only on string values.

Comment: Sorry, phone answer, forgot the map

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
print(list)
```

If you code a "**print**" inside the "**for**" loop, the print will be called according to the number of items inside your list, and since each "**print**" you call, prints in each line, that´s the expected result.

Note to self: I shouldn't use `list` because it will shadow the builtin list object.